# Find value in JSON string

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq

I have a string stored to a text file (or variable) which looks like this and I just need the value from *"ItemsQueued"* to be stored in another variable. Please note that all items occur twice in this string and I need both item values.

```
[{"Description":"blablabla","RemoteServerID":"982734298437234","DisplayClass":101,"ActiveWorkers":0,"TotalWorkers":1,"State":13,"ItemsQueued":0,"BytesQueued":0,"LastWorkerSubmitTime":1592553946,"CurrentTime":1592554151,"ItemsReplicated":456,"BytesReplicated":188588980},{"Description":"blablabla","RemoteServerID":"982734298437234","DisplayClass":100,"ActiveWorkers":0,"TotalWorkers":6,"State":13,"ItemsQueued":0,"BytesQueued":0,"LastWorkerSubmitTime":1592553615,"CurrentTime":1592554151,"ItemsReplicated":403459,"BytesReplicated":1061944812437}]
```

Any ideas? I am not a developer and all the `sed` examples I found don't fit to my use case.

Comment: Did you see that there are two occurences of "ItemsQueued" in the string? Which one do you need?

Comment: The example text shows both instances of *"ItemsQueued"* are `0` -- the Q. would be clearer if each instance in the example had different values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the data appears to be JSON, the obvious solution is to use `jq`:

```
$ jq '.[].ItemsQueued' file
0
0
```